# keep a $_GET variable always as "ac" OR "ar" values

Tags: php

I want to keep `$_GET['st']` i.e. `$status` to be `ac` OR `ar` in any circumstances, for exeample if user changes something inside the address bar.

```
if(!isset($_GET['st'])){header('Location: notes.php?st=ac');}  
else{$status = $_GET['st'];}  
if(!($status == 'ac' || $status == 'ar')){header('Location: notes.php?st=ac');}
```

How to write the first and the third line in one single line?
Or any other shorter solution?

Comment: If you got a downvote at the same time as my comment to Nick, it was a pure coincidence.  I don't downvote questions that include proof of effort.  (That said, I don't find this question to show extreme effort or worthy of a neutralizing upvote.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it makes it hard to read, you can make the assignment in the `if` statement, using the ternary operator to set an invalid value if `$_GET['st']` is not set:

```
if (($status = $_GET['st'] ?: '') != 'ac' && $status != 'ar') { header('Location: notes.php?st=ac'); }
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/49pRp)

Note that if you're using PHP7+ you can use the null coalescing operator `??` to avoid Notice level errors if `$_GET['st']` is unset:

```
if (($status = $_GET['st'] ?? '') != 'ac' && $status != 'ar') { header('Location: notes.php?st=ac'); }
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CYfUZ)

As @mickmackusa points out, the code can be further simplified using `in_array`:

```
if (!in_array($status = $_GET['st'] ?? '', ['ac', 'ar'])) { header('Location: notes.php?st=ac'); }
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HTZeb)

Comment: it would be shorter and easier to scale up with `in_array()`.